# Envoking catastrofic failure of MOSFET

Tags: mosfet

I would definitively like to know how a catastrophic failure of a MOSFET may be evoked considering its factuall that, overvoltage is imperative to destruction. We also know the technology is also important to consider, but for this post I would like to emphasize planar and trench. If however, people would like other techs I may update this post to accommodate them too.

I do not disclude radioactivity methods but rather more interested in "leads" of device attached to juice.

Now then, what methods and combinations do mayhem.

EDIT: The worst catastrophic failure possible is all I am asking.

EDIT#2: MOS transistor is to be vaporized with no remains but a brief audible tone.

Comment: anything outside of safe operating area.

Comment: Buy or construct an outrageously large inductor. Use the transistor as a switch to enable a large current to flow in the inductor. Now, turn off the transistor. If the energy stored in the inductor is large enough, it should destroy the transistor. I would say 1000 Joules should be enough.

Comment: the energy switched from inductance would cause vaporization?

Comment: Apparently you are looking for something with an effect akin to explosives. I doubt if this is possible in the way that you want. (To rapidly and completely vaporize a solid object is not an easy thing to accomplish.) Either way, I am not sure how this can be an electronics design question.

Comment: You can calculate the energy in the inductor using a simple formula. E = 0.5*L*I^2. You just need to store enough energy in the inductor to vaporize your MOSFET (how much is that, anyway? Datasheet normally does not include that information.) Then, yes, it should vaporize. Or at least parts of it should vaporize. Strangely, I have never had to design a self-vaporizing MOSFET circuit yet in my career.

Answer (score 4):

1. Not reading and understanding all aspects of the data sheet
2. Over temperature
3. Over power rating
4. Over voltage source to drain
5. Over voltage source to gate
6. Over current drain to source
7. Transient voltage application any lead w.r.t. any other lead
8. Forward current excess through body diode

Comment: want the worst possible not like prior to edit were it was left rather safe

Comment: Hey - Then just dial up any of the 2 -> 8 parameters in my answer to the highest level you can achieve.

Comment: how about now? only now has this truly encompassed a need for engineering methods

Comment: If you have to ask at this point it is clear that you are totally clueless. Go find some other endeavor to invoke your excitement and brushes with near death.

Comment: Place the device in close proximity to a wet tantalum that has internally 'self-healed' one time too many would do it as well :)